# ASP.NET Core Identity & Web API Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a ASP.NET Core 3.1 website and web api, the project it is working with ASpNetIdentity in a SQL Server database, the website part is working fine... also, I can authenticate the web api and get an access_token... but when I try to access my resources /api/vehicles, I get a Login redirection to the login page...

Startup.cs/ConfigureServices

```
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.Cookie.Name = "AgencyCookie";
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);//.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddDbContext<AgenciaDeTransporteContext>(o =>
        {
            o.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IAgenciaDeTransporteRepository, AgenciaDeTransporteRepository>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetAllResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.AllClients);

        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Startup.cs/Configure

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
```

VehiclesController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class VehiclesController : ControllerBase
{

    private readonly IAgenciaDeTransporteRepository _repository;
    private readonly ILogger<VehiclesController> _logger;
    public VehiclesController(ILogger<VehiclesController> logger, IAgenciaDeTransporteRepository repository)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetVehicles()
    {           
        return Ok(_repository.GetVehicles());
    }
```

Config.cs

```
new Client
        {
            ClientId = "myClient",
            ClientName = "My Custom Client",
            RequireConsent = false,
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>{new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
            AccessTokenLifetime = 60 * 60 * 24,
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
            RequireClientSecret = false,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            AllowedScopes =
            {
                "myAPIs"
            }
        }
```

[image]

But when I use the token is sending me a "redirect" to the Login page...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check your token on jwt.io? Also check issuer and similar properties. Maybe you are issuing tokens with properties that are not valid when checking them.
Also if you are logging, this can be a great source of debug information for auth-stuff.

Comment: I have Serilog configured, but there is not information showing about the "success" attemps, just the failed ones... How should I get more info? [13:41:31 Information]
Starting host...

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[0]
      Invalid password for user 24b1b794-7d51-4fec-9b47-e0eaff3b4521.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager[2]
      User 24b1b794-7d51-4fec-9b47-e0eaff3b4521 failed to provide the correct password.